# How do I pass an object in the rails URL helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having an issue understanding how to setup the routes in rails to pass an object into the URL helper.

I added a new method `add_item`

```rb
  def add_item
    @item = Item.create(item_params)
    puts @hospital.inspect
    puts @item.inspect
    @hospital.items << @item

    respond_to do |format|
      if @hospital.save
        format.html { redirect_to hospital_url(@hospital), notice: "Item was added to hospital" }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @hospital }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @hospital.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I added the corresponding route

```
  resources :hospitals do
    member do
      post :add_item
    end
  end
```

but when I run my test that uses

```
      post add_item_hospital_url(@hospital), params: { item: { item_code: item.item_code, description: item.description, gross_charge: item.gross_charge } }
```

the @hospital in the test is not nil but on the controller, it is. What am I doing wrong?
My routes seem to be okay.

```
add_item_hospital POST   /hospitals/:id/add_item(.:format)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instance variable `@hospital` is `nil` in the controller because it has not been set. Maybe you could add a `before_action` to set the value of the instance variable or just add it to the `add_item` method.

When passing models into the URL helper the id of that object can be found within the params hash

```rb
class HospitalsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_hospital, only: :add_item
  
  def add_item
    # ... your code here
  end

  private
    def set_hospital
      @hospital = Hospital.find(params[:id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      # handle exception
    end
end
```

Comment: I see! So how does it work when you use the URL helpers and pass the @var into it? I see them doing this on the update and other methods.

Comment: It seems that in your test file you are defining `@hospital` somewhere in the code, and that is why it works, but the controller knows nothing about the instance variables of the test, and thats why you have to set it again from the `:id` param

Comment: Ah! i see! So when we pass it into the URL helper the id of that obj can found within the params. Thanks!